# "IncludePaths" in gulp-sass scss folder content

Tags: sass, gulp

I think I know the answer, but just to verify. Does the IncludePaths option in gulp-sass need to be a path with all scss files, or does that directive looks for only scss files in that folder and ignore other files. I ask because I have a bower package with a scss file that needs compiling, but the .scss file is in the main directory and not its own separate sub-directory.

Comment: Try it both ways and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

It does not need to be in a subdirectory with only SCSS files, and other files in the directory will be ignored.